# MQTT "invalid protocol version" error with Ubuntu, mosquitto, and paho-mqtt

Tags: networking, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm currently working on an MQTT project using an NVIDIA Jetson running Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed mosquitto (version 2.0.15) as my MQTT broker and paho-mqtt (version 1.6.1) for my Python MQTT client.

I'm encountering an issue where I consistently receive an "invalid protocol version" error with an "mid" (message identifier) code of 1 when attempting to publish messages to my MQTT broker. I have double-checked my code and configuration, and I believe I am specifying the correct protocol version (MQTTv5) in my Python MQTT client as mosquitto v2.0.15 supports MQTTv5 and MQTTv3.1.

The broker server and publish client are running on the same device/network.

The MQTT broker is indeed running:

```bash
gabe@gabe-desktop:~$ systemctl status mosquitto
```

```
mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-01-06 19:10:01 CET; 1h 35min ago
     Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
           man:mosquitto(8)
 Main PID: 22604 (mosquitto)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4180)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mosquitto.service
           └─22604 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

Jan 06 19:10:01 gabe-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Mosquitto MQTT Broker...
Jan 06 19:10:01 gabe-desktop systemd[1]: Started Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
```

and port 1883 is listening on addresses: `localhost:1883` and `ip6-localhost:1883`.

```bash
gabe@gabe-desktop:~$ netstat -at
```

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:1883          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:40283         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:42269         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:34941         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:40451         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:gpsd          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:40283         localhost:47786         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 gabe-desktop:35130      13.107.5.93:https       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    108 gabe-desktop:ssh        Gabes-MBP:53006         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 gabe-desktop:35140      13.107.5.93:https       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:40283         localhost:47788         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:47786         localhost:40283         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:47788         localhost:40283         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:40283         localhost:47272         CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:1883      [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:gpsd      [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Here is the Python code and error when attempting to create a publish connection:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


# MQTT broker information
BROKER_ADDRESS = "localhost"
PORT = 1883
TOPIC = "testing"
RESPONSE = {
    0: "connection succeeded",
    1: "connection failed - incorrect protocol version",
    2: "connection failed - invalid client identifier",
    3: "connection failed - the broker is not available",
    4: "connection failed - wrong username or password",
    5: "connection failed - unauthorized"
}


def on_publish(client, data, mid):
    print(f"Connected to broker with status: {mid}: {RESPONSE.get(mid, 'Unknown')}")


def main():

    client = mqtt.Client(client_id="jetson", protocol=mqtt.MQTTv5)
    # Set the callback function for when the publisher connects to the broker
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    # Connect to the broker
    client.connect(BROKER_ADDRESS, PORT)

    # Publish a message to the "testing" topic
    message = "Hello, world!"
    client.publish(TOPIC, message)

    # Keep client running "forever"
    client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Connected to broker with status: 1: connection failed - incorrect protocol version
```

I also tried protocol version `mqtt.MQTTv31` and received the same error.

All the resources online have to do ensuring the mosquitto config file is properly configured. However, I have double checked this and this seems to be the case.

To ensure the MQTT broker server was indeed running correctly I performed the following test in two separate terminals

Terminal 1:

```bash
gabe@gabe-desktop:~$ mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t test
```

Terminal 2:

```bash
gabe@gabe-desktop:~$ mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t test -m "hello world"
```

I get the "hello world" output in terminal 1.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77770822/edit) the question to include the section of the mosquitto logs (`/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`) that shows startup and the error. And what happens if you set the protocol to `mqtt.MQTTv3`?

Comment: @Brits provided a solution that does not need the logs. Therefore, I won't be adding these messages to the question. Thanks for the extra information though.

Comment: You should always include the logs in a question like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def on_publish(client, data, mid):
    print(f"Connected to broker with status: {mid}: {RESPONSE.get(mid, 'Unknown')}")
```

`on_publish` is "called when a message that was to be sent using the
publish() call has completed transmission to the broker." and [is passed](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L2065C9-L2069C1):

> *client:*     the client instance for this callback
> *userdata:*   the private user data as set in Client() or userdata_set()
> *mid:*        matches the mid variable returned from the corresponding publish() call, to allow outgoing messages to be tracked.

You appear to be assuming that the `mid` indicates whether the connection is successful or not (as per the docs copied above; it does not). .

So what is happening (well, what happens when I test your code) is that you are successfully connecting to the broker and then successfully publishing a message. However once the message has been transmitted your `on_publish` is called (which incorrectly prints an error message).

I subject you intended something like:

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, reasonCode, properties):
    print(f"Connected to broker with status: {reasonCode}")

def on_publish(client, data, mid):
    print(f"Publish completed: {mid}")


def main():
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id="jetson", protocol=mqtt.MQTTv5)
    # Set the callback function for when the publisher connects to the broker
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_publish = on_publish
...
```

Comment: Thank you for referencing the docstring and pointing out the incorrectly printed error message. Indeed, your solution works. Thank you for the quick response. Much appreciated!